# What is the most lightweight way to render graphics Gentoo?

Tags: linux, terminal, gentoo, graphics

Basically, I am exploring `Gentoo`, and I would like to be able to perform some kind of graphics rendering (open a jpg, or draw basic shapes, or even set the colors of individual pixels if I have to).

I do not have any desktop or window manager, and I would rather not need one, but that is exactly the question. What is the most lightweight/simplest way to render graphics?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can display graphics using the Linux frame-buffer interface without X11 or Wayland at all.

[The `fbida` package](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/media-gfx/fbida) includes the `fbi` image viewer, which can run directly on the virtual console. You can't get much more light-weight than that.

Answer (score 0):

While not as lightweight as direct framebuffer access, [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) has no dependencies on the X server, and provides a much broader selection of applications, including image viewers and video players.

Check out [Is it possible to view media on the console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79409/is-it-possible-to-view-media-on-the-console) for software recommendations, many of them SDL-based.

Note that unless we're talking about a very old computer or an embedded system, you won't gain a substantial amount of memory or CPU time by not using X.